# Liferay DXP 7 consuming remote EJB, java.rmi.UnmarshalException: failed to load return type: class java.lang.Object

Tags: java, ejb, liferay, weblogic

I'm trying to consume a remote EJB from Liferay DXP 7.
My portal is deployed in weblogic 12.2.1.3.0, my client is a Spring MVC Portlet and
I'm using wlthint3client.jar.
When I try to lookup for the EJB it throws the next exception:

12:34:34,567 ERROR [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '10' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'][ImprimeCurpControllerPortletViewController:233] java.rmi.UnmarshalException: failed to load return type: class java.lang.Object; nested exception is: _     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mx.com.procesar.esar.trabajador.ejb.ImprimeCurpEJB = javax.naming.CommunicationException: failed to load return type: class java.lang.Object; nested exception is: _   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mx.com.procesar.esar.trabajador.ejb.ImprimeCurpEJB [Root exception is java.rmi.UnmarshalException: failed to load return type: class java.lang.Object; nested exception is: _  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mx.com.procesar.esar.trabajador.ejb.ImprimeCurpEJB] [Sanitized]

The remote interface is in WEB-INF/lib, but I don't know what's happenig here?
Do you have any idea about what's wrong?
Thank you so much for reading

Comment: It rather looks that your domain API library containing `mx.com.procesar.esar.trabajador.ejb.` package is not visible on classpath. Is it available on classpath (OSGi bundle with proper exports or bundled with your bundle).

Comment: The APi is bundled within my bundle, I installed it on my local maven and add it to the bundle as a dependency, it's a spring bundle build with maven, I think configuration is diferent (because I don't have a bnd.bnd file), shoul I do a diferent process?

Comment: Do you deploy it as an osgi bundle jar, or as a legacy war/wab?

Comment: It's a war bundle, built with Spring MVC and Maven